# Siamese LSTM for document similarity using keras giving input error

Tags: python, keras, lstm, siamese-network

I have written this code to use the Siamese method to calculate the similarity of two documents. I want to embed my vectorize layer (embedding is performed using Google News Dataset) of two separate documents using vectorization approach and then feed it to LSTM and output of LSTM goes into Cosine function to measure the similarity of two documents.

```
#importing libraries
from __future__ import print_function
import gensim
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
nltk.download('punkt')

from tensorflow import keras
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, LSTM, Bidirectional, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras import layers

#Loading pre=trained word2vec model

from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

# You need to dowload google pre-trained model using below link
# https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit
#Change the path according to your directory

model_path = 'D:\GoogleNews_vectors_negative300\GoogleNews_vectors_negative300.bin'   
w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=True)

#Setting Parameters for model

class DocSim(object):
    def __init__(self, w2v_model , stopwords=[]):
        self.w2v_model = w2v_model
        self.stopwords = stopwords
        
    def vectorize(self, doc):
        """Identify the vector values for each word in the given document"""
        doc = doc.lower()
        words = [w for w in doc.split(" ") if w not in self.stopwords]
        word_vecs = []
        for word in words:
            try:
                vec = self.w2v_model[word]
                word_vecs.append(vec)
            except KeyError:
                # Ignore, if the word doesn't exist in the vocabulary
                pass

        # Assuming that document vector is the mean of all the word vectors

        vector = np.mean(word_vecs, axis=0)
        return vector
        
        
    def Siamese_cosine_sim(self, vectorA, vectorB):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True),input_shape=[vectorA,vectorB])
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
        outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(left_doc,right_doc)

        """Find the cosine similarity distance between two vectors."""
        csim = np.dot(left_doc, right_doc) / (np.linalg.norm(left_doc) * np.linalg.norm(right_doc))
        if np.isnan(np.sum(csim)):
            return 0
        return csim
 

    def calculate_similarity(self, withdigits_source_rules, withdigits_target_rules=[], threshold=0.8):
            """Calculates & returns similarity scores between given source rules & all
            the target rules"""
            if isinstance(withdigits_target_rules, str):
                withdigits_target_rules = [withdigits_target_rules]


            source_vec = self.vectorize(withdigits_source_rules)
            results = []

            for rule in withdigits_target_rules:
                target_vec = self.vectorize(rule)
                sim_score = self.Siamese_cosine_sim (source_vec, target_vec)
                if sim_score > threshold:
                    results.append({
                        'Siamese Sim Score':sim_score,
                        'Target Rule':rule
                    })


                # Sort results by score in desc order
                results.sort(key=lambda k : k['Siamese Sim Score'] , reverse=True)

            return results

ds = DocSim(w2v_model)

#Two documents data
withdigits_source_rules =set(["2.1 Separation of trains","2.3.1.2 Level crossing obstruction","2.2.1.1 Safety is compromised if a train proceeds without a movement autority","Principle: The method of signalling must maintain a space interval between trains that is safe.","2.1.1 Context"])

#Calculate the similarity score between a source rule & a target rule.


if isinstance(withdigits_source_rules, str):
    withdigits_source_rules = [withdigits_source_rules]
   

# This will return one target rules text with a similarity score

for rule in withdigits_source_rules:
    sim_scores= ds.calculate_similarity(rule, withdigits_target_rules)

    

    
    # Printing the output in text file
    
    print("Source rule: {} \n\nSimilarity with Target Rule is \n\n {}\n".format(rule, sim_scores) , file=open("output.txt", "a"))
    print("\n")
    
    
    # Printing output in Jupyter
    
    print("Source rule: {} \n\nSimilarity with Target Rule is \n\n {}\n".format(rule, sim_scores) )
    print("\n")
```

I am getting following error if someone can help me to solve this issue along with LSTM input function?

```
TypeError: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_shape'
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#add) for adding layers to a Sequential model. The `add` method only accepts one parameter - `layer`. If the passed argument is not a layer instance, it raises `TypeError`, which is precisely the error it threw. I guess, you wanted to pass the `input_shape` parameter to the `LSTM` layer (line after creating Sequential model). Just move it inside the LSTM layer and it should work fine.

Comment: It works fine for me. Now I am getting a new error. `TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.`